# Auto-merge single line conflicts in git

Tags: git, merge

We have a large number of generated PHP files within a git repo.  These files are generated when someone uses an editor within the application to create certain content.  We need to keep the content in a deploy-able form, hence why it is checked into git.

The annoyance is that the generated files have a comment at the top such as:

// created: 2016-07-21 09:24:25

In a lot of instances this timestamp is the only change to the file.  However, git of course sees this as a conflict when both local and remote have changed.  This results in a large number of manual merge conflicts to resolve on pull.

Is there a way to instruct git to auto-merge just this line to "Ours" instead of raising a conflict?

I have searched and found solutions that will auto-merge the whole file, "ours" or "theirs" and also "smudging", but I don't think any of these really do what we need.  We want the // created: comment checked in, but we just want git to auto-merge conflicts for that specific line.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should remove that field altogether: "Time created" does not contain any new information that isn't already contained in the git log.

Comment: It's not my field unfortunately.  However it is a good suggestion to edit the application and find where it is generating the // created:  comment and remove it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to instruct git to auto-merge just this line to "Ours" instead of raising a conflict?

Not directly, no. You can instruct `git merge` to use a "merge tool" (which would normally be some GUI for merge resolution) and implement a custom tool that does what you need; but I would rather create a little script, which does the following (and should not be that hard depending on which environment you're using - Windows/Unix/bash/ruby etc.):

- Run `git merge` with the proper options.
- If the script detects no conflict (parsing the output and/or exit code from `git merge`), you're done.
- Else, load the conflicting files (you can get them from `git status` which should be a little easier to parse than the output from `git merge`)
- Detecting and fixing the conflict you're interested automatically in should be pretty straightforward with a regexp.
- Save the file.
- Check to see if it contains further conflict markers; if not, `git add`.
- When you're done with all files, and there were none with conflict markers, then `git commit`.

After this, either the merge is complete, or you have to do the usual conflict resolution with all your timestamps already resolved.